# Office 365 inbox rule for "Other emails"

Tags: office-365, exchange-server

We just moved to Office 365.

For an Office 365 account I can have a "Primary email address" and a few "Other email addresses". 
We used those "other" email addresses for promotions, system mails, etc. and sorted them automatically into different subfolders.

Now with Office 365  I can't find an inbox rule that applies to a specific BCC email address. There is "Sent to" and similar things, but I can only select an account, but not an individual email address. And if I select this account, it tells me it's ambiguous.

Any ideas?

**Update**: Figured out the account thing. I can create a contact with this email address and then select it. This works. But only for CC and not for BCC.